# SSRS Row Number within table excluding hidden rows

Tags: reporting-services, expression, hidden, row-number, ssrs-expression

I use the following expression to obtain a row number for a table in SSRS:

```
=RunningValue(CountDistinct("Table1"),Count,"Table1")
```

I also use an expression for the row visibility property. Lets just say that the Visibility expression is

```
=IIf(Fields!MyField.Value + Fields!MyField.Value <> 0, False, True)
```

My expression for the row number does not consider if the row is visible or not.

I could obviously change my dataset query, but is it possible to just alter my Row Number expression to only include rows that aren't hidden?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can probably achieve this by combining the logic of your two expressions.

Say you have a simple DataSet and a simple Tablix based on this:

[image]

[image]

Here, *RowNum* is calculated as:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!val1.Value, CountDistinct, "Tablix1")
```

Next, let's hide some rows using an expression based on the other two fields:

```
=IIf(Fields!val2.Value + Fields!val3.Value <> 0, False, True)
```

[image]

This breaks *RowNum*, but we can amend the expression to ignore the hidden rows. We do this by NULLing them out (i.e. for SSRS set as `Nothing`) - `CountDistinct` will not consider any `Nothing` values:

```
=RunningValue(IIf(Fields!val2.Value + Fields!val3.Value <> 0, Fields!val1.Value, Nothing)
    , CountDistinct
    , "Tablix1")
```

Now *RowNum* is ignoring the hidden rows as required:

[image]